# Symfony KnpMenuBundle route matching for similar-routes

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

Lets say I have a **collapsible menu**, where one entry in the collapsible part is mapped to the route:

`test/index`

How can I achieve that the the collapsible menu stays open and the entry inside is marked as the active one if I change the site location to lets say:

`test/create` / `test/update` / `test/detail` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your MenuBuilder you can match those routes with a switch and call `setCurrent()` on the item you want to be current. For example:

```
// The MenuBuilder must have access to the container
$request = $this->container->get('request');
switch ($request->get('_route'))
{
    case 'route_create':
    case 'route_update':
        $menu->getChild('Index')->setCurrent(true);
        break;
}
```

This will set the MenuItem 'Index' to current, if 'route_create' or 'route_update' is the current route.

Another appoach could be to match all routes as you normally did, then call `setDisplay(false)` on them to hide them. I didn't try this, but I think this should work, too.